# glPrimitiveRestartIndex could not be resolved

Tags: c++, opengl

I am learning OpenGL with the Redbooks v8 at the moment. But I'm stuck at the `glPrimitiveRestartIndex()` function, because it cannot be resolved.

My setup: 
OS: ubuntu 14.04, 
Compiler: g++ v4.8.4, 
Linked GL and glut. 
the exact error message is:

> error: ‘glPrimitiveRestartIndex’ was not declared in this scope

I included the following libs:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
enter code here
```

Any idea why this function could not be resolved?

What additional information is needed to fix this issue?

Comment: What OS/compiler? What libraries you're linking with? What is exact error message? `glew.h` probably should be included first.

Comment: OS: ubuntu 14.04, Compiler: g++ v4.8.4, I linked GL and glut.
the exact error message is: error: ‘glPrimitiveRestartIndex’ was not declared in this scope.
including glew.h doesn't change a thing.
btw: i also included #include <GLES3/gl3.h>. without this lib, most gl* function are not declared.

Comment: I don't really understand why you would include `<GLES/gl3.h>`? This is Ubuntu, so I'm guessing it uses an X server to run desktop GL. GLES is for embedded applications and mobile devices like cell phones / tablets. To be honest, I don't even think ES supports primitive restart indices. Use `<GL/gl3.h>` if you must (but `GL/glew.h` should be doing all this for you).

Answer (score 0):

Minimal test compiles fine:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

int main(void) {
    glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation line is `gcc test.c -lGLEW -Wall`.

If you have problems with that minimal example - then something is fundamentally wrong with your setup, but I bet it isn't the case. If it is, please let me know.

If it compiles but your code doesn't - then it is a mistake in your code, either include order or defines (both direct `#define` and `-D` compiler flags).